# Same origin policy violated?

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

Heh,
I'm using jQuery AJAX Call to pull data from a self hosted webservice (same domain), but it always return 0, which indicates a cross domain problem. But this shouldn't be a problem.

Any suggestions how to fix this? Thanks!

**Website running my Script**

```
http://www.mysite.com/facebook/el_login
```

**My AJAX Call:**

```
var data = 'username=' + username.val() + '&password=' + password.val()
$.ajax({  
             url: "http://www.mysite.com/api/v01/account/exists.json",   
             type: "GET",        
             data: data,       
             cache: false,  
             complete: function(transport) {
              if(transport.status == 200) {
                  alert('Success');
              } else {
                  alert('Failed ' + transport.status );
              }
           }

         });  
  })
```

Firebug Request Headers:

```
Request Headersview source
Host    www.mysite.com
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.8) Gecko/20100722 Firefox/3.6.8
Accept  */*
Accept-Language en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Proxy-Connection    keep-alive
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
Referer http://www.mysite.com/facebook/el_login
Cookie  sessionid=xxx
```

**Edit:**

Okay, it seems that AJAX Calls on static sites (same server) are working. My Webservice Backend is based on Django, Apache2 and mod_wsgi .. maybe there's a reason why this fails.

Comment: Looks okay. You are sure you are always using `http://` and not mixing it with `https://`? No differing ports? No automatically dropped or added `www.`?

Comment: Have you tried adding `function(transport, textStatus)` in the callback and seeing whether `textStatus` gives more detailed info?

Comment: textStatus return null which indicates an aborted request.

Comment: Have you tried pasting the URL into a browser to confirm that it's correct?

Comment: Strange. This looks okay to me. Just to exclude the possibility, you don't have any entries in your `hosts` file (say, from a past server move) that could interfere?

Comment: Firebug Displays www.mysite.com as the Hostname. The Webserver is setup behind a router (different ip) which routes to internal webserver.

Comment: @Henrik What's in `data` at request time? That's getting appended to your GET request URL, could that be messing you up?

Comment: @Lazarus Added my data var (my querystring which works)

Comment: I'm guessing the extra `})` at the end is a typo (or a completion of a previous block)? What happens if you use `success` and `error` instead of `complete`? (Yes, I know it should return the same thing, but does it?)

Comment: yap, }) belongs to the block before.

Comment: What happens if you build your URL with: `'http:// + location.hostname + '/api/v01/account/exists.json'` ? Or just use a relative URL without the protocol and host?

Comment: @Pointy Same URL is built. Still failing :)

Comment: Well, there's got to be something wrong, because it's obviously possible to do what you're trying to do. Can you tell if the requests are making it to your server? Are there server-side logs?

Comment: Apache's access.log doesn't display any requests for this webservice method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, after some hours of Starcraft 2 figured it out.
I wired my Submit Button with

```
$('#submit').click(function ()
```

which seem to create some problems with jQuery Ajax

**Solution:**
Use the "old" style to wire up your ajax call.

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" onClick="sendLogin()"  />
```

and

```
function sendLogin() {  
  var query_data = { username:  'test', password:  'test'};

  $.ajax({  
             url: "http://www.mysite.com/api/v01/account/exists.json",   
             type: "POST",        
             data: $.toJSON(query_data),       
          dataType: 'application/json',
          contentType: 'application/json',
             complete: function(transport) {
             if(transport.status == 200) {
                  alert('Success');
              } else {
                  alert('Failed ' + transport.status );
              }
           }
         });  
}
```

Comment: Odd. does it work if you use `$('#formID').submit(function...` and change input type to submit (and return false)?

Answer (score 1):

For debuggin I use:

```
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
    debugger; // TODO: Remove in production.
}
```

and in the ajax call use

```
error: showResponse
```

Have you tried using the following parameters:

```
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
```

Comment: my webservice doesnt require a content type if I provide a Querystring

Comment: he's passing an object in the "data" property to jQuery