# Cross-domain Requests with jQuery doesn't work in Facebook App

Tags: jquery, facebook, cross-domain

I want to make a HTTP request in order to receive the contents of the home page of the logged-in user of facebook.com inside my Facebook App. The app loads inside an iframe. I am using the Cross-domain Ajax mod for jQuery made by James Padolsey: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/cross-domain-requests-with-jquery/ . This mod works fine for pages like google.com as presented in the examples.

Unfortunately if I try something like:

```
$('#container').load('http://www.facebook.com/');
```

I get no result and no errors. Furthermore if I try:

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://www.facebook.com',
            success: function(html){
                process(html);
            },
            error: function(){
                debug("error");
            }
        });
```

I get an error in the Firebug Console which says: `data.results[0] is undefined`.
This error is inside James Padolsey's Ajax mod so it doesn't have anything to do with any previous code I wrote in my script.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Benny, and welcome to SO. I've got a similar problem a few weeks ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457778/same-origin-policy-violated

Comment: Hi Henrik, thanks for the link. I tried your suggestion but when I click the button I get "Failed 0" in my alert box.

Answer (score 0):

JSON doesnt work cross domain. You need to use JSONP or better yet in the getJSON call use the "callback=?" parameter.

For example

```
$.getJSON("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?callback=?&access_token="+fbtoken, function(rtnmsg) {

}
```

Where fbtoken is your access token and rtnmsg is the return object. This one works for me.

Cheers

Comment: That function may work for accessing the Graph API, but that's not what I want. I strictly want to parse the Facebook homepage of the user that is logged in. Using the getJSON call that would translate to something like this: <code>$.getJSON("http://www.facebook.com/", function(rtnmsg) {...}</code>
If you try this from a facebook app you will see that rtnmsg is undefined